# If at least one record has value 1 then return 'Yes'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server that contains a column `yesno`.

If at least one of the rows has the column `yesno=1` then I need to return only one row yes.

I made a query that returns for every row if is yes or no.

```
(select (case when isnull(coalesce(dl.yesno,'2'),'2')='1' then 'Yes' else 'NO' END) 
 from table dl where dl.ID='A5454322-C239-4FF2-A458-8A9BD79C1839')
```

Comment: Need a bit more information. Please could you provide some example rows and example result?

Comment: Why are you nesting `COALESCE` and `ISNULL`?

Comment: For example when i execute this query i get this                          nr| yesno |     id(foreignkey)                                                  1 | yes   |     A5454322-C239-4FF2-A458-8A9BD79C1839                            2 | no    |     A5454322-C239-4FF2-A458-8A9BD79C1839                                                      and now i need if one of this is yes to return me onle one row yes .

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'yes'
where exists (select 1 from the_table where yesno = '1');
```

SQLfiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/069204/1

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'yes' where exists (select * from MyTable where [yesno]='1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 'yes' from table where yesno = 1
```